# Vector that is orthogonal to one vector in a plane, automatically the normal?

Tags: orthogonality

I'm trying to understand why if a vector is orthogonal to one vector in a plane, why it wouldn't be orthogonal to all vectors in that plane?

Sketches/diagrams would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider two vectors in the same plane that are orthogonal.

Answer (score 2):

Because  given a vector $u$ in the plane $\alpha$, a vector $v$ can be orthogonal to $u$ and stay in the same plane $\alpha$. As an example:
$$
\vec u=(1,0,0)^T \qquad \vec v=(0,1,0)^T$
$$
are orthogonal but stay in the same plane $x-y$.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the $xy$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the vector $\hat{\text{i}}$. $\hat{\text{j}}$ is orthogonal to $\hat{\text{i}}$ but it's not orthogonal/normal to the plane.